# Variable is undefine - React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this global variable for config values that I require in index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

// Config
const Dir = require('./Config/dir.jsx');

// Components
import Header from './Components/Header.jsx';

ReactDOM.render(<Header />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

this is the content of my dir.jsx

```
module.exports = {
    css: 'public/css/',
    js: 'public/js/',
    img: 'public/img/'
}
```

When I accesssed the config variable in my header.jsx components using { Dir.css } it gives me an error "Dir is not defined".

Here's the header.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';

require('./../Stylesheets/header.scss');

class Header extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <nav className="navbar navbar-default">
                    <div className="container-fluid">
                        <div className="navbar-header">
                            <button type="button" className="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span className="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                <span className="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span className="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span className="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>
                        <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">{ Dir.img }</a>
                        </div>
                        <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                            <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li className="active"><a href="#">Link <span className="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Header;
```

Here's the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Did you tried with `import Dir from './Config/dir.jsx'`?

Comment: You say it's undefined in your Header component, you should post that code and the actual line its crashing on

Comment: The first thing I notice is your defining Dir in the file you posted but it's being used in Header. This really isn't doing you any good and you need to make sure that either you pass Dir as props to the header component or require Dir inside the Header component file but without seeing the Header file I can't give more insight

Comment: editted my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I presume you're using `webpack` to build your project**

`webpack` won't import files unless there're used. In your case, you're just importing `Dir` and not using anywhere. `webpack` will skip this import for obvious reason.

There are 2 things you can do:

1. Import `Dir` inside the `Header` component
2. Pass the `Dir` as a `prop` to the `Header` component. Like this `<Header dir={Dir} />`. This can be accessed by `this.props.dir` inside the `Header` component.

I'll prefer the `1st` way of doing.

P.S. You shouldn't use `import` and `require` together.

Comment: You can refer [this](https://github.com/praneshr/petch/blob/master/webpack.config.babel.js) `webpack` config to make your `scss` compilation better

Comment: what does it do, sorry im not yet that familiar in this kind of stack.

Answer (score 2):

Import `Dir` inside the `Header` component as
`import Dir from './Config/dir.jsx'`